# Node.js` "http.get" doesn't return full response body to a browser but just a piece of <head> tag. How to get full response?

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I experience a strange behavior with Node.js `http.get`. I make a request to a url with ajax and want to get the result into my browser. But I only get some piece of a `<head>` tag content and nothing more, no `<body>` content. But if I send the result to system console (`console.log(chunk)`) I get the result as I want to get - the full page. Here are my steps:

```
// Simple jQuery Ajax GET
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/myapppath",   // send to my app's url
    data: {foo: "bar"},
    success: onLoad,    // the callback, see just bellow
    error: onError,
    dataType: "text"
});

// With this callback function I want to insert the result into <div id="baz">
function onLoad(resp) {
   document.getElementById("baz").innnerHTML = resp;
}

// In /myapppath
http.get("http://stackoverflow.com/", function(result) {
   result.setEncoding('utf8');
   result.on("data", function(chunk) {
      console.log(chunk); // this successfully returns the whole page but into system console
      res.end(chunk);   // this returns just a piece of <head> tag into the browser.
   });
});
```

So in my `<div id="baz">` I only get some piece of `<head>` tag of `http://stackoverflow.com/` request, no `<body>` tag and its content. That's all I get in `<div id="baz">` instead of the whole page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=dd6898efd655"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=8a5907e853ab">

    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed of recent questions" href="/feeds">
        <script type="text/javascript" defer>
        </script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">          StackExchange.init({"stackAuthUrl":"https://stackauth.com","serverTime":1374771485,"styleCode":true,"enableUserHovercards":true,"site":{"name":"Stack Overflow","description":"Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers","isNoticesTabEnabled":true,"recaptchaPublicKey":"6LdchgIAAAAAAJwGpIzRQSOFaO0pU6s44Xt8aTwc","enableSocialMediaInSharePopup":true},"user":{"fkey":"b1d105a0cf61e49216c5750a6ad60dec","isAnonymous":true}});
        StackExchange.using.setCacheBreakers({"js/prettify-full.js":"6c261bebf56a","js/moderator.js":"7cf00e91ce39","js/full-anon.js":"c5bf51314708","js/full.js":"02e9182c23d3","js/wmd.js":"2f79c03846d5","js/third-party/jquery.autocomplete.min.js":"e5f01e97f7c3","js/mobile.js":"e8e23ad37820","js/help.js":"6e6623243cf6","js/tageditor.js":"450c9e8426fc","js/tageditornew.js":"b6c68ad4c7dd","js/inline-tag-editing.js":"8e84e8a137f7","js/revisions.js":"7273bb714bba","js/review.js":"2b3ae123e376","js/tagsuggestions.js":"aa48ef6154df","js/post-validation.js":"bb996020492a","js/explore-qlist.js":"1c5bbd79b562","js/events.js":"37756ef3ba47"});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        StackExchange.using("gps", function() {
             StackExchange.gps.init(true);
        });
    </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            StackExchange.ready(function () {
                $('#nav-tour').click(function () {
                    StackExchange.using("gps", function() {
                        StackExchange.gps.track("aboutpage.click", { aboutclick_location: "headermain" }, true);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
</h
```

But in `console.log(chunk)` I get the whole page printed in the console as I said above.

What is going on? Why `http.get` doesn't return full response into browser? What did I miss? What cuts the response?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`console.log(chunk);` doesn't actually log the entire page at once, but it does keep logging each `chunk` as more `'data'` arrives.

[`res.end()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding), on the other hand, becomes a no-op after the 1st call as it closes the connection, so only the 1st `chunk` is included.

What you can do is [`res.write()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding) each `chunk` of `'data'`, waiting for [`'end'`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) to `res.end()`:

```
http.get("http://stackoverflow.com/", function (result) {
    result.on('data', function (chunk) {
        res.write(chunk);
    });
    result.on('end', function () {
        res.end();
    });
});
```

Or, since `result` is a [Stream.Readable](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) ([`IncomingMessage`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage)) and `res` is presumably a [Stream.Writable](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) (guessing a [`ServerResponse`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse)), you should be able to [`.pipe()`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) them:

```
http.get('http://stackoverflow.com', function (result) {
    result.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Nodejs' async nature sometimes blows my mind

Answer (score 11):

Your data event is firing multiple times, but you can only "end" your output once...  you should probably refactor your handler as follows...

```
// In /myapppath
http.get("http://stackoverflow.com/", function(result) {
    var responseParts = [];
    result.setEncoding('utf8');
    result.on("data", function(chunk) {
        //add this chunk to the output to send
        responseParts.push(chunk);
    });
    result.on("end", function(){
        //now send your complete response
        res.end(responseParts.join(''));
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, works like a charm. Thank you. Now I understand how to use it.

Comment: excuse me, but what is 'ret' supposed to be?

Comment: @atrioom it was a typo of the "res" above (corrected)... res is the http response object for the connection from the client browser.